# Apex compile error ONLY when installing package in sandbox/prod - not in scratch

Tags: salesforcedx

I've created an unlocked package. It installs fine in scratch, but when I install it to sandbox (or prod) I get a compile error:

```
Apex compile failure, Details: line 116, column 29: Variable does not exist: User.Address
```

Funny thing is that I don't have this variable or any reference to User.Address in my code. But I do have a dependency on SF CPQ, a managed package which have been installed already in sandbox/prod.

Where could it be coming from, and why would it be different for scratch vs. sandbox?

Comment: Is the class that fails to compile in your project? What's at the line referenced in the error?

Comment: Are sandbox, prod and scratch all on the same API version?

Comment: @JohnTowers I've got two apex files, in one there's a comment on line 116, on the other just a debug statement using a object other than User. I'm not using User anywhere in my code except in a unit test class, which doesn't use the Address field. The same classes were running fine in sandbox before I converted to a DX project, did no changes, and created package. That's so strange. I'm thinking the offending line could be in a dependency (the managed package I've mentioned), since I can't find it in my code.

Comment: @DavidReed API version 43 in sandbox, which is summer 18. Looks to be 43 in scratch orgs as well, although I must say I've seen the winter 18 logo on some scratch orgs, but the one I've installed the package in is Summar18 Api43, and also in the project file sourceApiVersion is 43

Comment: I've got a feeling it has some relation with the dependencies. I've added a dependency to a managed package, because I'm using some objects from that. Maybe I should just drop the dependency, since I anyway must install that package manually in the scratch org? And use dependencies only for my own unlocked packages?

Comment: I tried different syntax for managed package dependency as well, and also to remove the dependency all together (since anyway I'd need to prep. the scratch org manually). In the end I went the mdapi route. Conversion takes literally 2 seconds, and uploading to any org a few seconds + running of unit tests. Compared with 10+ minutes just to create a package version and the same for installing it (with errors) I conclude that I'll wait until Unlocked packages are GA. YMMV. Still my source is all DX so I'm happy enough.

Comment: Doesn't your error tell which class it is from? For me, it tells, and the error is from existing Apex in the org rather than anything from my unlocked package. You might relate to my issue: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252395/unlocked-package-deployment-fails-to-a-sandbox-org